# Реализация условия для графа

Tags: c++, алгоритм, графы

<del>**Немного несущественной информации:** только что был контест на кодфорсесе, была задача [*С*](http://codeforces.com/contest/624/problem/C) для второго дивизиона. Пришла в голову идея, как можно решить данную задачу, но слишком поздно. А теперь, я поинтересовался, можно ли с помощью этой идеи решить данную задачу.</del>

**Так вот, к сути:**

Необходимо обработать список ребер неориентированного графа следующим образом: если одна вершина графа соединена с двумя или более вершинами, а они между собой не связаны, то тогда выводим на экран <del>большой кукиш</del> слово "NO" и досрочно выходим из программы, иначе, пишем "YES".

Поиск по интернетам ничем не помог, как можно реализовать данный алгоритм? **Желательно на c++.**

Comment: *"а они между собой не связаны"* - это значит, что между ними нет ребра, или пути?

Comment: Между ними нет ребра. Т.е., к примеру, есть вершина, с которой соединены ребрами еще две вершины, но последние выше указанные две вершины не имеют общих ребер

Comment: Получается, нужно выделить полный подграф, я правильно понял?

Comment: **1 2,
1 3,**
3 4,
4 5

Это пример списка ребер. Дальше выделенного куска уже не нужно идти, т.к. не соответствует моему условию. Следовательно, при завершении выполнения данного примера должно показать кукиш.

Comment: Нужно проверить данное условие для какой-то одной конкретной вершины? Какие ограничения на входные данные?

Comment: Допустим, для начала, для одгой стоит сформировать реализацию. А так, надо для всего графа. ограничение на входные данные: количество вершин не больше 500

Comment: Если необходимо проверить для всего графа, то можно просто посчитать количество ребер в одной компоненте связности - это должно занять меньше времени, чем проверять наличие ребра между каждыми вершинами. В чем причина выходить досрочно? Или после этого алгоритма запускается еще один?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35333/discussion-between-semior-and-soon).

Answer (score 2):

Я эту задачу не решал, но первое что приходит в голову - рассматривать именно `отсутствующие` рёбра. Если ребра нет - значит в его вершинах `a` или `c`. Дальше воспользуемся стандартной идеей. Пусть на 1 найденном ребре в первой вершине а, во второй с. Дальше отсюда идёт вся компонента связности (по отсутствующим рёбрам). Повторим для каждой компоненты.

После чего во все остальные вершины (не достигнутые на предыдущих шагах) пишется `b`.
Осталось только проверить что граф подошёл.

Сложность порядка O(n^2 + M) ~ O(n^2)

UPD. Прошло все тесты. http://codeforces.com/contest/624/submission/15821318